# Anchor Link Libraries not working at all in my React project

Tags: html, reactjs, react-scroll

I have tried multiple anchor link libraries for ease of active classes in order to scroll to sections of my page when clicking through the nav bar. Using a normal anchor element, as in `<a href='#content'>test</a>` snaps to the element with the corresponding ID, however no scroll libraries have worked at all. My latest attempt, React-Scroll, for example. Here is my nav component (simplified for readability):

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import styles from './SideNav.module.scss'
import { FaGithubSquare, FaLinkedin } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { Link, animateScroll as scroll } from 'react-scroll'

const SideNav = () => {   
    return(
        <div className={styles.sideNav}>
            <div className={styles.navElements}>
                <section className={styles.brand}>
                    <h1 className={styles.name}>Josh Bangle</h1>
                    <h3>Web Dev. Voice Actor. Dad. Nerd.</h3>              
                </section>
                <ul className={styles.navList}>
                    <Link to='test1' spy={true} smooth={true} offset={50} duration={500}>test link</Link>
                </ul>
                <div className={styles.socials}>
                    <a href='https://www.github.com/joshbangle' rel="noopener noreferrer" target='_blank' className={styles.github}><FaGithubSquare size={50} /></a>
                    
                    <a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/joshbangle' rel="noopener noreferrer" target='_blank' className={styles.linkedin}><FaLinkedin size={50} /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    )
}
export default SideNav
```

And the component with the corresponding ID in it:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Contact = () => {
    return (
        <section id='test1'>
            <ContactContent>
                <Headline>Contact me</Headline>
                <h1>Feel free to reach out to me through LinkedIn, or email me directly at:</h1>
                <Email>joshua.bangle@gmail.com</Email>
            </ContactContent>
        </section>
    );
}

export default Contact;
```

I have tried multiple packages, multiple ways of writing the anchor, and just nothing at all happens. I'm starting to wonder if somehow another package I have installed is interfering with the scroll functionality of packages. If that is possible at all, I can link to the github repo if anyone is willing to check it out. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: shouldn't the `to='test1'` be `to='#test1'` ?

Comment: Apparently not with the React-Scroll library.

Comment: looks ok https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-glade-webm6?file=/src/App.js - there must be an error printed in the javascript console. could be that the error is preventing execution of other scripts. i'd start checking there

Comment: None showing up in the chrome dev console =\

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. I was using a layout component with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';

import SideNav from '../SideNav/SideNav'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Skillset from '../Skillset/Skillset'
import Projects from '../Projects/Projects'
import Contact from '../Contact/Contact'
import TestNav from '../../TestNav'



const LayoutWrapper = styled.div`
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
`

const ContentWrapper = styled.div`
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
`

const Layout = (props) => {


    return (
        <LayoutWrapper>
            <TestNav />
            <SideNav  />
            <ContentWrapper>
                <Skillset/>
                <Projects/>
                <Contact/>
            </ContentWrapper>
            
        </LayoutWrapper>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

The `overflow` styling was somehow getting in the way of the anchor function. I've removed that and have refactored my code to better implement the sticky side bar feature I was going for. I'm not entirely sure why the overflow was having this effect, but removing it fixed the issue for me.